# WebAPI APIExplorer Documentation does not pick up my Summaries comments

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

Using http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages documentation guide and applied these on each public API controllers

```
/// <summary>
///  My own description comments
/// </summary>
```

but somehow NONE of my Summaries comments do get picked up by the XML generator ApiExplorer.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, right click on the project and go to "Properties". In the "Build" tab check the "XML documentation file" checkbox.

Then copy the generated XML file from the bin folder into the project, commonly "App_Data" folder. Reference the file in the `HelpPageConfig.cs` of the Help Page MVC area. There will be a commented out line that looks something like `config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Doc.xml")));` Change the XML file name and uncomment the line.

Comment: Yes, the problem on that post is that the file name on the HelpPageConfig has to be exactly the same on that you set on the Project Properties and that normally takes the project name. Great catch Dmitry.